# How to round times in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, time, nscalendar

I am struggling for days trying to solve this puzzle.
I have this code that calculates time IN & OUT as decimal hours: 
(6 min = 0.1 hr)~(60 min = 1.0 hr)

```
 NSUInteger unitFlag = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute;

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:unitFlag
                                           fromDate:self.outT
                                             toDate:self.inT
                                            options:0];

NSInteger hours   = [components hour];
NSInteger minutes = [components minute];


if (minutes <0) (minutes -= 60*-1) && (hours -=1);

if (hours<0 && minutes<0)(hours +=24)&& (minutes -=60*-1);

if(hours<0 && minutes>0)(hours +=24)&& (minutes = minutes);

if(hours <0 && minutes == 00)(hours +=24)&&(minutes = minutes);

if(minutes >0)(minutes = (minutes/6));

self.blockDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%d", (int)hours, (int)minutes];
```

The green lines show what the code does, what I am looking for is to round the minutes like the blue lines, 1,2 minutes round down to the next decimal hr, 3,4,5 minutes round up to the next decimal hr

[image]

What I am try to achieve is:
If the result is 11 minutes the code return 0.1 then only after 12 minutes it will return 0.2. What I am trying to do is if the result is 8 the code returns 01, but if it is 9 will round to the next decimal that is 0.2 and so on.
The objective is do not loose maximum of 5 minutes in each multiple of 6 in worst cases. Doing this the maximum lost will be 3 minutes in average

Any input is more than welcome :)
Cheers

Comment: Incoherent. Six times round to 0.1 but seven times round to 0.3? What pattern is that?

Comment: @matt Hi sorry my mistake I made this picture only for illustration. now is edited for your better understanding. Let me know if you need more clarification thanks for your time :)

Comment: Please don't rely on images for your explanation.  Please write a coherent, well defined explanation of the logic you wish to implement.

Comment: Comments should not be used to clarify.  The question body itself should be as clear as possible.  Please edit your question to be as clear and concise as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Your goals seem incoherent to me. However, I tried this:

```
let beh = NSDecimalNumberHandler(
    roundingMode: .RoundPlain, scale: 1, raiseOnExactness: false, 
    raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false
)
for t in 0...60 {
    let div = Double(t)/60.0
    let deci = NSDecimalNumber(double: div)
    let deci2 = deci.decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior(beh)
    let result = deci2.doubleValue
    println("min: \(t) deci: \(result)")
}
```

The output seems pretty much what you are asking for:

```
min: 0 deci: 0.0
min: 1 deci: 0.0
min: 2 deci: 0.0
min: 3 deci: 0.1
min: 4 deci: 0.1
min: 5 deci: 0.1
min: 6 deci: 0.1
min: 7 deci: 0.1
min: 8 deci: 0.1
min: 9 deci: 0.2
min: 10 deci: 0.2
min: 11 deci: 0.2
min: 12 deci: 0.2
min: 13 deci: 0.2
min: 14 deci: 0.2
min: 15 deci: 0.3
min: 16 deci: 0.3
min: 17 deci: 0.3
min: 18 deci: 0.3
min: 19 deci: 0.3
min: 20 deci: 0.3
min: 21 deci: 0.4
min: 22 deci: 0.4
min: 23 deci: 0.4
min: 24 deci: 0.4
min: 25 deci: 0.4
min: 26 deci: 0.4
min: 27 deci: 0.5
min: 28 deci: 0.5
min: 29 deci: 0.5
min: 30 deci: 0.5
min: 31 deci: 0.5
min: 32 deci: 0.5
min: 33 deci: 0.6
min: 34 deci: 0.6
min: 35 deci: 0.6
min: 36 deci: 0.6
min: 37 deci: 0.6
min: 38 deci: 0.6
min: 39 deci: 0.7
min: 40 deci: 0.7
min: 41 deci: 0.7
min: 42 deci: 0.7
min: 43 deci: 0.7
min: 44 deci: 0.7
min: 45 deci: 0.8
min: 46 deci: 0.8
min: 47 deci: 0.8
min: 48 deci: 0.8
min: 49 deci: 0.8
min: 50 deci: 0.8
min: 51 deci: 0.9
min: 52 deci: 0.9
min: 53 deci: 0.9
min: 54 deci: 0.9
min: 55 deci: 0.9
min: 56 deci: 0.9
min: 57 deci: 1.0
min: 58 deci: 1.0
min: 59 deci: 1.0
min: 60 deci: 1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your time matt but to retrieve the decimal time I can not use doubles only int, I have no idea why simply does not work, in the app any chance to make this calculation in the IF statement? By the way congratulation for you book, we have in our library :)

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying. I am simply matching your input (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) to your desired output (0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1). They match perfectly. I don't see what else you can want. Computer programming is an imitation game - I have imitated the stated behavior exactly. Do you even know what you are talking about?

Comment: Ok Mr matt, sorry if I do not have your knowledge, what I was trying to explain is that the code I have in my app must be preserved, so I am thinking how can I insert your wonderful code nested in my last IF statement to return only the minutes in decimal that I need.

Comment: I'm not going to write you code for you. I'm showing you _a technique_. I am teaching you _what rounding is_ and _how_ to do it. You should _use_ this technique in _your code_.

Comment: This is not what I asked, but anyway thanks for your reply. lets see if I get other way to do it... Thanks